# Can't verify domain for Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, safari

I'm trying to set up Google Apps for Business for a client of mine. The problem is that I'm unable to verify the domain ownership. Every method Google provides for the verification process eventually fails.

For example, if I try to go with the HTML file upload verification technique, Google Apps is unable to detect the file.

I click the address under the error message after Google Apps says it can't detect the HTML file and I'm unable to see the file as well. I get a `Safari can't find the server` error. If I put the “www” before the domain name then I'm able to see it. Once I see it, the address also works by removing the “www” in the front. So it totally baffles my why it doesn't work at the first time or why Google Apps can't detect it.

Same goes for the other methods (adding a CNAME/TXT record or meta tag addition) as well.

The Apache configuration for the domain has been set that it also accepts visits without “www” in front of the domain name; I tried it and it works okay. Also I've a naked “A record” to the domain's IP address and other records seem intact as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled the situation.

It turns out that when registering my domain to my server, I added it with "www" in front. Therefore even though it's DNS record entries were fine, it was having issues with accessing.